# Concept of Conversations in Teams Bot development

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a Microsoft Teams Bot using the NodeJS v4 Bot Framework. This is the first time I have gone and developed a bot and it seems to me it is missing a core concept, conversations / previous message context. When the bot asks me how I am going and I answer "good" in the next message and following messages it doesn't seem to store in an object how I am going.

I have a work around for this by pushing answers into an array but it just seems strange that previous message context hasn't been implemented... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you might be missing is an understanding of [Bot state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). This link gives an overview of the *types* of state (user vs conversation) as well as places you can *store* state (e.g. memory, Azure blob storage, etc.). Be aware that Cosmos DB, proposed in the article, can be an expensive option because of the high read state of bots (every turn results in a read, which is part of what Cosmos pricing is based on), so MongoDB for instance could be another possible option.

Another approach to "state" though is the concept of "dialogs", where there a specific "guided conversation" the user might be going through. As an example, in an flight booking scenario you would need departure location, destination, date, time, etc., so this is a multi-turn "mini conversation" and dialogs do their own state management in this context. See "[Dialogs within the Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)".

As an aside, the "array" approach you're taking is kind of similar to the in-memory state option, but it requires you to manage things 100%, it can't easily be scaled (with the built in state stuff, it's easy to switch out memory to another option), and it might not be multi-user safe (depending how you're working with the array, if you're saving one per user or so).

Hope that helps

Comment: Agree with the answer here but also wondering what the specific need is here. There are a number of ways to consume and use inputs from users, including saving in the waterfall dialog context if it is just needed for a specific conversation and doesn't need to be remembered for the entire session or across sessions.